# Why am I running this error with Youtube API, when it is defined above? Did I miss an import?

Tags: python, api, youtube

I have imported my API key and enterted the following code

```html
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
import pandas as pd
import pprint 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pd

DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyBSLZrW68GMY3X9E8D_VCcVcMJxZ9k-ImY"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(q, max_results=50,order="relevance", token=None, location=None, location_radius=None):

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=q, type="video",pageToken=token,order = order,part="id,snippet", maxResults=max_results, location=location, locationRadius=location_radius).execute()

    title = []
    channelId = []
    channelTitle = []
    categoryId = []
    videoId = []
    viewCount = []
    likeCount = []
    dislikeCount = []
    commentCount = []
    favoriteCount = []
    category = []
    tags = []
    videos = []
    
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube video":

            title.append(search_result['snippet']['title']) 

            videoId.append(search_result['id']['videoId'])

            response = youtube.videos().list(
                part='statistics, snippet',
                id=search_result['id']['videoId']).execute()

            channelId.append(response['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId'])
            channelTitle.append(response['items'][0]['snippet']['channelTitle'])
            categoryId.append(response['items'][0]['snippet']['categoryId'])
            favoriteCount.append(response['items'][0]['statistics']['favoriteCount'])
            viewCount.append(response['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'])
            likeCount.append(response['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'])
            dislikeCount.append(response['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount'])
 
        if 'commentCount' in response['items'][0]['statistics'].keys():
            commentCount.append(response['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount'])
        else:
            commentCount.append([])
 
        if 'tags' in response['items'][0]['snippet'].keys():
            tags.append(response['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'])
        else:
            tags.append([])

    youtube_dict = {'tags':tags,'channelId': channelId,'channelTitle': channelTitle,'categoryId':categoryId,'title':title,'videoId':videoId,'viewCount':viewCount,'likeCount':likeCount,'dislikeCount':dislikeCount,'commentCount':commentCount,'favoriteCount':favoriteCount}

    return youtube_dict
```

This runs without error. Then I am trying to use the code in the following cell:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns 
from youtube import youtube_search

and I run the following error: 
ImportError: cannot import name 'youtube_search'

Does anyone know how to fix this?